# How do I import a cpython module inside a Python script which will be used by a C++ program?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x

I have a script1.py where I am importing binascii.

```
import binascii
```

When I try to use this inside a C++ program using PyImport_ImportModule(), I get the following error.

```
   import binascii
ImportError: No module named 'binascii'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
   from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
   from apport.report import Report
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
   import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 437, in <module>
   import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'
```

When I do the following from terminal it works.

```
python3.5 -c "import binascii"
```

So how can I use these cpython modules from a C++ program?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did something wrong when installing Python. try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-serial
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your steps but it didn't work.I tried my program on another machine where it worked. So seems you are correct about something being wrong with Python installation.